# Android onAnimationEnd executed even activity is finished

Tags: android, android-animation

So onAnimationEnd or onBackPressed I want to start similar activity, but when I finish activity earlier with onBackPressed onAnimationEnd starts activity too so I got it in stack ... is there a way to control whether activity is finished and then do not execute onAnimationEnd?

Comment: It's nor clear please explain more, or provide some code.

Comment: try using `isFinishing()` in `onAnimationEnd `